# Rsync is not syncing properly?

Tags: rsync

So I run the command:

```
edmund@cat:/images/edmund/gallery$ rsync -rzvO --exclude='.svn' ./ edmund@dog.com:/images/edmund/gallery/
```

My local directory is empty, while the directory on the remote server is full of pics. This is the result of running the command:

```
    sending incremental file list

    sent 24 bytes  received 12 bytes  5.54 bytes/sec
    total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

However, nothing is in my folder. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Could it be an SSH issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on the local server which has no pictures you need to connect to the remote server. You need to reverse your syntax:

```
edmund@cat:/images/edmund/gallery$ rsync -rzvO --exclude='.svn' edmund@dog.com:/images/edmund/gallery/ ./
```

Syntax is rsync [Source] [Destination]. See man page for [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).